# Date/Time Clock Script Doesn't Honor Font Setting

Tags: javascript

The following Date/Time clock script works great but it doesn't honor the simple @font-face setting, as shown below.
There's nothing I can see that would prevent it from working. What could it be?

The following Date/Time clock script works great but it doesn't honor the simple @font-face setting, as shown below.
There's nothing I can see that would prevent it from working. What could it be?

```
<style>

@font-face {
  font-family: "Euphorigenic-Regular";
  src: url("fonts/Euphorigenic-Regular.eot"); /* IE9*/
  src: url("fonts/Euphorigenic-Regular.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), /* IE6-IE8 */
  url("fonts/Euphorigenic-Regular.woff2") format("woff2"), /* chrome、firefox */
  url("fonts/Euphorigenic-Regular.woff") format("woff"), /* chrome、firefox */
  url("fonts/Euphorigenic-Regular.ttf") format("truetype"), /* chrome、firefox、opera、Safari, Android, iOS 4.2+*/
  url("fonts/Euphorigenic-Regular.svg#Euphorigenic-Regular") format("svg"); /* iOS 4.1- */
}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

function date_time(id) {
    date = new Date();
    year = date.getFullYear();
    month = date.getMonth();
    months = new Array('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'Aug', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec');
    d = date.getDate();
    day = date.getDay();
    days = new Array('Sun', 'Mon ', 'Tues ', 'Wed ', 'Thu ', 'Fri ', 'Sat ');
    h = date.getHours();
    if (h < 10) {
        h = "0" + h;
    }
    m = date.getMinutes();
    if (m < 10) {
        m = "0" + m;
    }
    s = date.getSeconds();
    if (s < 10) {
        s = "0" + s;
    }
    const pmOrAm = h > 12 ? "PM" : "AM";
    const hoursIn12 = h > 12 ? h - 12 : h;
    result = '' + days[day] + ' ' + months[month] + ' ' + d + ', ' + year + ' ' + hoursIn12 + ':' + m + ':' + s + ' ' + pmOrAm;

    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = result;
    setTimeout('date_time("' + id + '");', '1000');
    return true;
}

</script>

<body>

<div style="font-family:Euphorigenic-Regular; position:fixed;" id="date_time"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">window.onload = date_time('date_time');</script> 

</body
```

Comment: You're missing a closing double quote in your `div`'s `style` attribute.

Comment: You forgot quote " so maybe that was the reason. It seems working now?

Comment: @A.Meshu Don't edit in corrections in the question, and definitely don't start refactoring code. Rolling back.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen sorry you right. I do it automatically sometimes...

Comment: Thanks for your replies and sorry guys. The double quotes is in my script but I left it out when copying it here. It's now fixed. I wish that were the problem, but the font I set still does not display.

Comment: I'm only familiar with the free Google web fonts (https://fonts.google.com/) and to a lesser extent adding fonts to a Windows 10 PC.   Is your code expecting to find these fonts on your web server? https://www.linotype.com/657646/euphorigenic-family.html